# Regex to match all word format except one format

Tags: regex

Here is string:

> $$START$$ should be matching along with $$MIDDLE$$
>
> $$NOTMATCH$$ this should NOT be matching
>
> $$LAST$$ this should be matching

In the above paragraph, I need to build a regex which can match all the Keywords($$[a-zA-Z]$$) except $$NOTMATCH$$

Until now, I have tried `(?!\$\$NOTMATCH\$\$)(\$\$([^\$\$]+)\$\$)` but It is not properly working and is not considering the $$ symbols in the end of Keyword, demo [here](https://regex101.com/r/bbwZWc/3).

Any suggestions are welcome.

Thanks in advance

Comment: It depends on what chars can be between `$$`s. If just letters, then [`\$\$(?!NOTMATCH\$)([a-zA-Z]+)\$\$`](https://regex101.com/r/2Mkk9w/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to build a regex which can match all the Keywords `($$[a-zA-Z]$$)` except `$$NOTMATCH$$`

You can use negative lookahead in the middle as this:

```
(?<!\$)\$\$(?!NOTMATCH)[^$\s]+\$\$(?!\$)
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2Mkk9w/4/)

- `(?!NOTMATCH)` is negative lookahead that will fail the match if we have `NOTMATCH` between `$$` characters.
- `(?<!\$)` is negative lookbehind to ensure we don't have `$` before our match.
- `(?<\$)` is negative lookahead to ensure we don't have `$` after our match.

Comment: yes, but it will also match $START$ and $$$START$$$ :(

Comment: In that case use: `(?<!\$)\$\$(?!NOTMATCH)[^$\s]+\$\$(?!\$)`